# Order results from Kohana ORM

Tags: php, orm, kohana

I'm using Kohana's ORM library, and I'm wondering if there is any way to order the results that are generated.

Example:

```
$priorities = ORM::factory('priority')->select_list('id','label'); //how to order these?
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What is `select_list`?

Btw, ordering in kohana is performed by `order_by()` method

```
...->order_by('field', 'asc')
```

More samples you can find at: http://kerkness.ca/kowiki/doku.php?id=building_complex_select_statements#order_by

Also that wiki contains a lot of usefull articles about kohana: http://kerkness.ca/kowiki/doku.php

Comment: a function that must have existed an one point, but doesn't now. saw it in these docs: http://docs.kohanaphp.com/libraries/orm

Comment: which kohana version are you talking about, v2 or v3? if v3 - then there is no such function. Go to the wiki url in my answer and read about kohana v3 orm in details.

Comment: Probably replaced by as_array('id', 'label') which returns an associative array of id => label which is perfect for handing off to a select list.

Comment: This is annoying, the kohana docs are all over the place and the official docs only showed 'order_by' and no way to use....

Comment: order_by() in kohana 2.3, you have to put something like this in your model.   protected $sorting = array('last_login' => 'desc', 'username' => 'asc');